# Provision EC2 machine in needed packages via CDK

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

Is it possible to initialize EC2 machine in CDK with needed packages?
Or only way is to create it first and then install needed packages?

Thank you for your answers an tips,

Answer (score 1):

The *UserData* can run the *cfn-init* script which will pull down Metadata passed in from CloudFormation,  In CDK, this can be done in one object with the *CloudFormationInit* class

From the CDK documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#configuring-instances-using-cloudformation-init-cfn-init

adding the init param into your aws_ec2.Instance definition (for python similar to)

```
aws_ec2.Instance(self, scope, ...
  init=aws_ec2.CloudFormationInit.from_config_sets(
    config_sets={'default': ['init']},
    configs={
      'init': aws_ec2.InitConfig([
         aws_ec2.InitPacakge.python(package_name='boto3'),
         aws_ec2.InitFile.from_asset('/usr/local/myscript.sh', 'scripts/myscript.sh')
      ])          
    }
  ), ...
)
```

this will result in the EC2 instance having the appropriate cfn-init scripting in the UserData section automatically, and load the *scripts/myscript.sh* into the instance with the *boto3* python package installed.

More information on **AWS::CloudFormation::Init** - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for UserData: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ec2.Instance.html#userdata

With UserData you can add commands which your EC2 Instance executes at (by default only first) launch.

E.g. for installing apache:

```
const userData = ec2.UserData.forLinux();
userData.addCommands('yum install -y httpd');

new ec2.Instance(this, 'instance', {
  userData: userData,
  ...
});
```

Another way would be to create a custom AMI which you use to start your EC2 instance. That AMI could have all packaged pre-installed.